# Lock a folder from internal storage programmatically Android(It should be like Forward Lock/DRM)

Tags: android, pdf, video, locking, drm

Want to lock a folder in the internal storage seems to be like Forward Lock (or) Using DRM.

**Example :**
It should be like locking a pdf file which asking for a password by default. So, in the same fashion my video file which is locked should ask for a password where ever it is opened.

Guide me with correct solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is not possible, but one think you can use encrypt and decrypt algorithms..

Comment: but encryption and decryption is taking time I tried it @Vijaykumar . Can you suggest me any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, except perhaps via a modified version of Android that you roll into a custom ROM.

Breaking this down into pieces:

- [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) is an operating system for mobile devices
- A modified version of Android is where you modify [the Android source code](https://source.android.com/) to incorporate your desired feature
- A [custom ROM](http://www.androidpolice.com/2010/05/01/custom-roms-for-android-explained-and-why-you-want-them/) contains a compiled edition of your modified version of Android, plus device drivers and related bits, so that the ROM can be installed on some specific model of Android device

An ordinary Android app cannot do what you are seeking.

Comment: can you be more specific? I didn't understand the thing you specify like **modified version of Android that you roll into a custom ROM.**

Comment: So, If I am not wrong? If I have control on the OS(I mean Android OS is Customised) then we can get the things like locking feature with password.

In a Single Shot It is a OS feature you mean am I correct? If not correct me. @CommonsWare

Comment: @KURUMADDALIANURAG: I would phrase it as "you can try to implement it with a modified version of Android on a custom ROM". Finding a way to implement it that both makes sense from the user's standpoint *and* does not break every app will be difficult.